# Springboot Multiple datasources Entityscan

Tags: spring-boot

I have two data sources each are dealing with different entities. I have set entity scan packages for entity manager to scan different packages. and also I have configured "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to update. when the application starts, the hibernate is creating tables in both the datasources. My requirement is to create tables mapped to corresponding datasources.

Comment: Did you try to put `data.sql` and `schema.sql` in  your **resources**  folder

Comment: No. I have two configuration files and two separate entity packages for two databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two files schema.sql(your ddl's like create alter drop) and data.sql(your dml's like insert, delete) for each datasource in your resources folder. Then you should put a property in your `application.properties` to run scripts when the application booting: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

After that in your `Application.java` class, create a method to run your scripts:

This is for first ds:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
   DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
   dataSource.setUrl("ds url");
   dataSource.setUsername("");
   dataSource.setPassword("");

   // schema init
   Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("scripts/schema-first.sql");
   Resource initData = new ClassPathResource("scripts/data-first.sql");
   DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new 
   ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema, initData);
   DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);

   return dataSource;
```

}

I think it should work.You can create another method for your second datasource.